# Threading and modal form windows

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, modal-dialog

VB.Net code.

I have a program where I am running a process in a thread and in that thread I need to have a pop up message information box that is non-modal. The main process is in a thread because it has to run in parallel and the user can initiate this process many times at the same time.

I read that the modal message box needs to be a custom form that is also ran from a thread to not block the program from continuing on. such as .Show() stops the program and waits for the user input. And you have to use .ShowDialog() via a thread

My code:

Calling initial thread:

```
Public Event Report As EventHandler
 
   'In a method
    Task.Run(Function() BackgroundThread())
    

Private Function BackgroundThread() As Task()
     RaiseEvent Report(Me, New System.EventArgs)
End Function
```

In the Report method I have a snippet of code that then calls the form window to pop up the modal window:

```
Private mDiaplayMessageBox As NonModalPopUp

Private Sub DisplayMessageBox()
        mDiaplayMessageBox = New NonModalPopUp()
        Task.Run(Sub() mDiaplayMessageBox.ShowDialog())
End Sub
```

The issue I am having is that when I am finished with the report method I want to close this popup message. But when there is more than one of these pop up windows open at a time, only the last window opened will close and the program loses the handle I think to the other pop up windows and they will not close.

To close the windows I have in the modal form this code

```
Public Sub CloseMe()
        'This will grab the thread that this window is running on, solves Cross-Threading issue.
        If Me.InvokeRequired Then
            Me.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf CloseMe))
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Me.BackColor = Color.Red

        Me.Close()
End Sub
```

This first time this code is called its will hit the Me.Invoke and then close the window. However, on any subsequent calls when it gets to Me.InvokeRequired this will then be set to false, not called the Me.Invoke and go to the Me.Close() but it will not close the window.

I tried to do something where I grab the Handle intptr value but when ever I vent just look at that value the program immediately throws a cross-threading exception.

All I want to do is close the other windows which does not seem like a hard task but I do not know what I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

One of approaches you can follow to achieve your goal might be as code below shows:
You can create a custom event which you can use as a “call” to listen to for the closure of your form.

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim frm2 As Form2
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        frm2 = New Form2
        Task.Run(Sub()
                     AddHandler CloseFrm2, Sub()
                                               Dim CloseMe As Action = Sub()
                                                                           frm2.Close()
                                                                           frm2.Dispose()
                                                                       End Sub
                                               If frm2.InvokeRequired Then
                                                   frm2.Invoke(Sub() CloseMe())
                                               Else
                                                   CloseMe()
                                               End If
                                           End Sub
                     frm2.ShowDialog()
                 End Sub)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        RaiseEventCloseFrm2()
    End Sub

End Class


Module EventHelper
    Public Event CloseFrm2()
    Sub RaiseEventCloseFrm2()
        RaiseEvent CloseFrm2()
    End Sub
End Module
```